# How do I print every iteration possible between a multiplication of two products in a list?

Tags: python

Given a list with numbers between `0` and `5`. I want every possible result of two numbers in this list that returns true for `(a ** 2 + b ** 2) < 12`.

My code for this is:

```
from random import choices
from math import factorial

nodes = list(range(0,6))
lis = []
for e in range(0,factorial(5)):
    nodesf = choices(nodes, k= 2)
    if not nodesf in lis:
        if (nodesf[0]**2 + nodesf[1]**2) <= 12:
            print(nodesf)
            lis.append(nodesf)
            lis.append(nodesf[::-1])
            print(lis)
        else:
            lis.append(nodesf)
```

But, as you can see, this is probably a horrible way to solve this.
If you see a more clear and efficient code to solve this, please, help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the [`combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) method from the built-in module, [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

for a, b in combinations_with_replacement(range(6), 2):
    if (a ** 2 + b ** 2) < 12:
        print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 2
```

The `combinations_with_replacement()` method is similar to the `combinations()` method, except the `combinations_with_replacement()` method allows one element to be used in the same combination more than once.

Do note that it does not include `1 0` as a solution as there already exists `0 1` in the results. If you want to include such, you can use the [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) method:

```
from itertools import product

for a, b in product(range(6), repeat=2):
    if (a ** 2 + b ** 2) < 12:
        print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 0
2 1
2 2
3 0
3 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ann, I need to get more in touch with itertools lib.

Answer (score 1):

#### What's wrong with your code ?

- Iterating through `range(0, factorial(5))` does not make a lot of sense to me : you're going to do 120 iterations. To solve this, you just need two compare each elements of `nodes` with the whole list, hence two `for` loops on your `nodes` : only 25 iterations.
- Why using `choices` to pick elements from `nodes` ? It's a stochastic operation, you won't be sure to go through every elements of the list.

#### Simple solution

If you care about permutation, i.e. you want to get both `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)` for example, a simple list comprehension should do the trick.

```
[ (a, b) for a in nodes for b in nodes if a**2+b**2<12 ]
```

Otherwise, just take a look at the perfect Ann Zen's answer using the `itertools` module :)

Comment: Thanks for the critique and the answer Nizil! In this case I do care about permutation, so Ann's answer is a better fit for my question.